# Angular 2 not updating *sometimes*

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

I have a Angular 4 Application running on Electron.

In my main component I run a service which opens a saved file and sets its parameters on an object called 'session'.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {


this.Service.ready.subscribe(() => {

  this.session = this.Service.session;
  console.log(this.session.name)

});

this.Service.startService();
  }
```

I either use the file dialog to open a session file or I load the last session file when initializing the application. I update my UI by subscribing to the 'ready' event that my service emits when it has finished loading the file. Note that for both opening the most recent file and loading a file using a dialog, it runs the same method.

**The problem:**
When opening a file a file through the dialog, the UI get's updated immediately. When loading the last session on startup, the UI doesn't get updated.

**What have I tried**
The service uses NgZone to trigger change detection.
The subscription shows that the correct session is set to the variable 'this.session'
I have tried using ChangeDetectorRef but no difference.

Why is there a difference in change detection when I use the same method and event to trigger it? Does it have to do with components that are still being initialized?

**Update to show Zone updating in Service**

from my Service:

```
loadSession(path: string): void {

    fs.readFile(path, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, (err, data) => {
        if (!err) {

            var session = JSON.parse(data);

            console.log(session);

            this.zone.run(() => {

                this.session = session;

                this.readyToStart();

                this.notify("Opened Session:", this.session.name, null);

                console.log("opened session");
            });

        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

My readyToStart method emits the 'Ready' Event

Comment: `The service uses NgZone to trigger change detection.` How does it look like?

Comment: Updated with service code

Comment: do you see the console.log(this.session.name) output?

Comment: Hmm maybe the  "this.session = session" only takes effect when you leave the zone? And so when your gui is informed, the assignment isn't effective yet?

Comment: @DavidBulté yes I see the output, also when I do the loading after a session is set, everything works fine. It seems to be something in the startup phase

Comment: Maybe try with a BehaviourSubject? When you get a new session, you put it on the BehaviorSubject. And you let the GUI subscribe to that BehaviorSubject iso the "ready observable".

Comment: Also when I click on any button, components seem to rererender and parts of the UI are updated but not everything

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `LoggerService` like this:

```
this.logger.tick_then(() => this.session = this.Service.session);
```

This will put this change on the next change detection cycle

Comment: Hi Dean, I assumed you are talking about this custom made service? https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/public/docs/_examples/lifecycle-hooks/ts/src/app/logger.service.ts I tried this but it doesn't change the problem